# Redirect url from one domain to another using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, iis

I have sub domain and main domain. I want to redirect all the url of subdomain to their domain. like if user will write

```
1) abc.example.com   then it should redirect to www.example.com
2) abc.example.com/mno/jkl_123.html then it should redirect to www.example.com/mno/jkl_123.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.example\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc.example\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And same as for other URL's of site. I have tried following rule in htaccess.

it is working for for images or point 1 type of URL which is defined above. But not working for Point 2.

Can anybody let me know what i need to change to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some small modifications:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.example\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Provided you placed your `.htaccess` style file in the correct location and it's interpretation is enabled at all in your http host configuration then this should work.

Also you need to have the host `abc.example.com` and `www.abc.example.com` defined and pointing to that location in the file system, *or* they have to be served by the default host inside your http server.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks #arkascha. I have windows server that why i am doin this way Also There is another .htaccess file in subfolders, that's why it was not redirect.